# Formulario se envía vacío

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario

```
<form  id="con" >
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 wow fadeInUp animated">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Nombre" id="name" name="firstname">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" name="email">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" id="phone" name="lastname">
                 <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Your Message" id="message"></textarea>
                 <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
             </div>
             <div id="success"></div>
             <button type="button" id="contact" class="btn btn-x3 wow bounceIn animated">Send Message</button>
         </div>

         <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

y posteriormente el archivo ajax

```
$("#con").click(function() {
    var url = "blog/admin/core/functions/contact.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),  
        success: function(data){
                     swal('Excelente.','Enviado','success')
                 }     
    });
    return false;
});
```

y resulta que solamente darle `click` al `input` me envía el formulario vacío

Answer (score 3):

Reemplaza:

```
data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
```

Por:

```
data: $("#con").serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-x3', function(e){
            var url = "blog/admin/core/functions/contact.php";
            e.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $("#con").serialize(),  
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                     swal('Excelente.','Enviado','success')
                    }     
            });
             return false;
        });
```

Comment: debes aceptar la respuesta de fredyfx que aporto en solucionar el problema marca la respuesta como solucionada en el visto gris, no responder a tu pregunta con la solución de fredyfx. Saludos :)

Comment: no lo interpretes a mal pero eso no fue la solución claramente dije que no me funcionaba así era otros elementos que fallaban

Comment: Ok ya comprendo saludos :)

Comment: Para mejores respuestas, mayores detalles ;)

Comment: mismo comentario antes descrito por otros usuarios =)